# uncaught syntaxerror:unexpected token => in build index.html

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, nw.js

I have a react website and it works fine in chrome when I build it. But when I put in into a linux nw.js browser, it through out an error:

```
uncaught syntaxerror:unexpected token =>
```

I use babel and es2015 to transpile. How should I fix this error?

Comment: What do version of ecmascript do you transpile to?

Comment: my babelrc is this:
{ "presets": [
    ["es2015", {"modules": false}],
    "stage-0",
    "react"
  ],
  "comments": false,
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-async-functions",
    "syntax-dynamic-import",
    "transform-async-to-generator",
    "transform-regenerator",
    "mobx-deep-action",
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-runtime"
  ]
}

Comment: most likely because this is un-transpiled code. This seems to be an arrow function in your code.